# How to data-bind on click function using knockout and durandal

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I have a topbar in my application which is being used in several html files. I made a html template of that topbar and I am including that html file in all the other html files where I need that topbar.

**main.html**

```
<style type = "text/css">

.glyphicon.glyphicon-user
{
font-size: 38px;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-refresh
{
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>

<div id="myElement">

<div id="includedContent"></div> // this is where included html file is rendered

 //here I have other contents 

</div>
```

**main.js**

```
$("#includedContent").load("./app/views/topbar.html"); // This is how I call that html file
```

Now, I get the html file and the topbar is rendered on the screen. In that top bar, I have a dropdown which has a **modal dialog** that gets called using **data-bind : click**. Other links are working fine but dialog box doesn't even get called. I am not sure what the problem is, maybe I should not call html inside another html like this in **durandal**.

This is my code for topbar

**topbar.html**

```
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar navbar-default blue-background">

    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">



        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <li><a href="#sync"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="color:white"></span></a></li>
                </div>

                <div style = "margin-right: 20px">
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <span data-toggle="dropbtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:white"></span>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a  data-bind="click:ChangePassword" style="font-size: 14px; color:blue;" ><label>Change Password</label></a>
                                <a id="Logout" href="#" style="font-size: 14px; color:blue"><label>Logout</label></a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </div>

            </div>

        </ul>


    </div>



      </div>

   </div>
```

topbar.js

```
  define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout','./changepassword'], function(router, app, ko,changepassword) {



return
{

    ChangePassword: function()
    {
      alert("!!!!!!");
       changepassword.show();

    }

 };
});
```

So, I get the dropdown but I don't get the dialog box when I click on change password. I hope I am able to explain my problem. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because you're using jQuery to load the topbar template into the correct space on each page, rather than using [Durandal's composition engine](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html) to do it for you. It's the Durandal composition engine that binds the view to the view model.

What you should typically be doing if using Durandal, is [create a shell page for your application](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Understanding-the-Starter-Kit), and the topbar resides there, bound using Durandal, thus allowing you to use the [Knockout click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html). Perhaps using the compose binding. The shell page then has an area defined to host the "pages" that make up the rest of your application. Typically you'd use the [Router](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html) for this.

I'm using Durandal and the only place I use jQuery in my entire application is in a couple of custom [Knockout bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I used the same approach as you suggested